# Where to ask about writing a test case for a specific method?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about Unit-Testing? The questions is on how to test a certain method (Java) for a race condition, I'm unsure if that belongs on Stack Overflow or if there is a more appropriate site for it.

Comment: Oh ! You should rephrase your post differently. Really thought that was off-topic until the very last word

Answer (score 3):

Try to write a general question that may be applicable to lots of people. Focus/narrow down your question on the exact circumstance you want to test for. Also include, if relevant, the name of the testing framework you use, and an example method where you have removed non-relevant parts of the method code.

If it is not a duplicate you may be able to ask a good question on this topic. It is definitely on topic for Stack Overflow. Try to avoid posting a dump of your own code; great questions usually write the code specifically for the question to only include the circumstances relevant for the question.